# Show $\ln (1+\frac{1}{x})$ is convex on the open interval $(0,1)$

Tags: real-analysis

I need this to one proof and have tried to do it from definition and I got:
$$\ln\left[\frac{\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{x_2}\right)^2\right]^\lambda}{1+\displaystyle\frac{1}{\lambda x_2+(1-\lambda)x_1}}\right]\geq0$$

Is a way to make it more simply?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\left[\log(x+1)-\log(x)\right] = \frac{1}{x^2}-\frac{1}{(x+1)^2} > 0 $$
implies that $\log\left(1+\frac{1}{x}\right)$ is convex on $(0,1)$.

Comment: Jack, you're answering all of the reseach-level queations today.  ;-)

Comment: @Dr.MV: LOL. Well, I am waiting for something really challenging to appear :)

Comment: What happened to all the great problems we used to see?